# Sending datetime value to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I want to send just date to a stored procedure and I wrote this C# code:

```
string[] pr = { "/" };

string[] s = txtStartDate.Text.Split(pr, StringSplitOptions.None);

term.Start_date = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(s[0]), Convert.ToInt32(s[1]), Convert.ToInt32(s[2])).Date;
s = txtEndDate.Text.Split(pr, StringSplitOptions.None);

term.End_date = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(s[0]),Convert.ToInt32(s[1]),Convert.ToInt32(s[2])).Date;
```

and I send it to the stored procedure like this:

```
public bool AddNewTerm(Term term)
{
     SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
        {
            new SqlParameter ("@termName",term.TermName),
            new SqlParameter ("@start_date",term.Start_date),
            new SqlParameter ("@end_date",term.End_date)
        };
     return SqlDBHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("AddNewTerm", CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters);
 }
```

but when it goes to the stored procedure say this:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

I see other topic but they cant help me

This is the stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.AddNewTerm
(
    @termName varchar(50),
    @start_date date,
    @end_date date 
)
AS
    insert into term(termName, start_date, end_date)
    values(@termName, @start_date, @end_date)
    RETURN
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at DateTime.Parse and DateTime.TryParse methods.

Comment: When you debug your application, what are the values of the two parameters?

Comment: for example 30/6/1390 12:00:00 AM

Comment: B0Andrew : for DateTime.parse say same error.

Comment: 1390? You need a datetime2 column

Comment: What is the format of the txtStartDate string?  You could use the ParseExact to TryParseExact with a format string to match the exepected date format.

Comment: the format of txtStartDate is yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: Downvoting the question because without debugging the app (as requested) this is tedious and just a bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find my answer by changing my way
I used [PersianCalendar Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx)  and store it `varchar`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message talks about a lower limit of 1/1/1753, so, supposing that you have parsed correctly your inputs (30/6/1390) the message seems clearly indicate that the two column `start_date` and `end_date`are of type `datetime`that has a lower limit of 1/1/1753.

So, to store a date with year less than 1753 you need a `datetime2` or `date` column that have a lower limit of 1/1/0001

[Here a quick reference](http://sqlhints.com/tag/datetime-vs-datetime2/) for the two datatypes

There is another problem in your code. You add the parameters to the array without specyfing their SqlDbType and in this way the Date are added as DateTime parameters that of course cannot accept a value below 1/1/1753. A workaround for your specific code could be.

```
public bool AddNewTerm(Term term)
{
     List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>()
     {
         new SqlParameter("@termName",SqlDBType.VarChar, 50) {Value = term.TermName},
         new SqlParameter("@start_date",SqlDBType.DateTime2, 0) {Value = term.Start_Date},
         new SqlParameter("@end_date",SqlDBType.DateTime2, 0) {Value = term.End_Date},
     };
     return SqlDBHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("AddNewTerm", CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters.ToArray());
 }
```

Comment: The stored procedure receives `date` parameters but what is the datatype of the two datatable columns `start_date` and `end_date`?

Comment: Steve :SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Comment: i found it by changing my way.i use by Persian Calendar Class and store them by varchar.

Comment: not the correct way to store a datetime. What happen if you need to search on that column? A mess. However I have understood you problem. It is the way in which you build the parameters. Without specifying the type the parameter will be created of DateTime type not of DateTime2. I will update the answer with my findings